# iText Chunks are written over each other

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, itext

I have a simple piece of code that splits a sentence (named content in the code) into tokens and then writes tokens in pdf file, but each in new line.

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("ticket.pdf"));
        document.open();
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
        String[] tokens = content.split("\\|");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(token, font);
            document.add(chunk);
            document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        }
        document.close();
```

But when I open the result pdf file, all of the tokens (chunks) are written over each other in the first line, like this:

[image]

Can anyone point to me what am I doing wrong here? Code is written in Spring Boot with Java 11, and iText version is 5.5.10

Comment: You never set the location of the chunk. If you are using iText 7 then You could set the location prior to adding it to the document like so `chunk.setRelativePosition(...)` or `chunk.setFixedPosition(...)`

Comment: Consider adding the chunks to a paragraph each and then adding these paragraphs to the document.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! That's all I needed, them to be in separate lines. I never used iText prior to this so I didn't know about paragraphs.